# How to increment font size changes with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, typography

Hi I want to change the font size of the page incrementally with jQuery how do I do that?

Something like:

```
$('body').css({'font-size':'+.01px'});
$('body').css({'font-size':'-.01px'});
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You could do so :

```
var fontSize = parseInt($("body").css("font-size"));
fontSize = fontSize + 1 + "px";
$("body").css({'font-size':fontSize});
```

[**jsFiddle example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/5G6W6/1/)

Comment: not working on chrome css('font-size') returns '10px'

Comment: The jsfiddle doesn't work for me, but the code is good enough to help out.

Comment: This code worked for me, though I targeted the `html` element. You will also need to set all of your font-sizes to use `rem` instead of `px`.

Answer (score 9):

You can't do it like that because the font propery is stored as a string, if you are sure the font size will be in pixels you could do it like this:

```
var fontSize = $('body').css('font-size').split('px')[0];

var fontInt = parseInt(fontSize) + 1;

fontSize = fontInt + 'px';
```

That might need modifying slightly I just wrote it without testing.

Answer (score 5):

It might depend on which version of jquery, but I have used the following

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" id="button" />
<div id="box"></div>
```

**CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(function() {
    $("#box").css("width","+=5");
   });
 });
```

Comment: This is for width not line height. It also does not work in Chrome as of today.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
jQuery("body *").css('font-size','+=1');
```

Comment: Thanks! Even though it's been a while since it was written, this answer is succinct and does exactly what I need. Not sure why this isn't the top-voted answer-- to clarify, I mean that genuinely; I'm not a javascript developer.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Increase font" /> <br />
<div id="text" style="font-size:10px">Font size</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn').click(function() {
        $('#text').css("font-size", function() {
            return parseInt($(this).css('font-size')) + 1 + 'px';
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ynhat/CeaqU/

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('id or class of what input').click(function() {
        $('div, p, or span of what font size your increasing').css("font-size", function() {
            return parseInt($(this).css('font-size')) + 1 + 'px';
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Be careful when using non-px font sizes -- Using Sylvain's code when parsing for an int when the font-size is 1.142857em would result in 2px!

parseInt(1.142857em) == 1

1 + 1 + 'px' == 2px

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how I did it with jQuery UI slider.

Example [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvQXRM)

HTML:

```
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="text">
        <h1>Hello, increase me or decrease me!</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div id="mySlider"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.text h1 {
  color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

JS:

```
$("#mySlider").slider({
  range: "min",
  min: 30,
  max: 70,
  slide: function(e, u) {
    $(".text h1").css("font-size", u.value + "px"); // We want to keep 30px as "default"
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var i = 15;

        $("#myBtn").click(function () {
            if (i >= 0) {
             i++
                var b = $("#myText").css({"background-color": "yellow", "font-size": i})

            }
        })
//If you want to decrease it too
        $("#myBtn2").click(function () {
            if (i <= 500) {

                i--
             var b = $("#myText").css({"background-color": "yellow", "font-size": i})

            }
        })
    })
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and readers need to understand how it once worked.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses percentages instead of using px and also does not require the size to be set or require style headers in the HTML.

HTML:

```
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<button id="btn">turn up</button>
```

jQuery:

```
var size = "100%";
$("#btn").click(function() {
size = parseFloat(size)*1.1+"%";// multiplies the initial size by 1.1
    $("p").css("fontSize", size);// changes the size in the CSS
});
```

**[Working jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/uh79vghu/)**